# Form method Post not working. Not running php file

Tags: php, html

There's seems to be a problem with my form method post i can't seem to make the php working. Whenever i press the submit button, it just sends me to the file directory which contains the php script and it never runs the code.

here is the html file:

```
<form action="includes/inquire-packages.inc.php" method="POST">
<label>Event Name</label>
<input type="text" name="e_name" placeholder="Enter Event Name*"/>

<label for="job">Day of the Event</label>
<input type="date" name="d_event" placeholder="Enter Date of Event*"/>


<label for="job">Time of the Event</label>
<input type="Time" name="t_event" placeholder="Enter Time of Event*"/>

<label for="job">End Time of the Event</label>
<input type="Time" name="e_t_event" placeholder="Enter End Time of Event*"/>

<label>Theme</label>
<input type="text" name="theme" placeholder="Enter Theme*"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

php file:

```
<?

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$c_id = $_REQUEST ['u_uid'];


$e_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['e_name']) ;
$d_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['d_event']) ;
$t_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['t_event']) ;
$e_t_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['e_t_event']) ;
$theme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['theme']) ;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$sql = "INSERT INTO event_table (event_name, event_date, event_time_start, event_time_end, cusact_id, theme, reserve_date_time, package_id) VALUES ('$e_name', '$d_event', '$t_event', '$e_t_event', '$theme', '$date', '$id');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: includes/inquire-packages.inc.php?insert=success");
}
```

Comment: What Error you are gettinh?

Comment: If PHP code is showing up instead of actually running, it means PHP is not running on your server or the PHP engine is disabled inside the directory.

Comment: @whoami Im getting a blank page with the file directory on the url.

Comment: @icecub I have a login system that works fine so i guess my php is running on my local host.

Comment: In that case try adepting your code to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // entire code here up till header() } else { echo 'isset was false'; }`

Comment: Oh wait. I see. You have errors inside your code. There are spaces everywhere where there shouldn't be any spaces.

Comment: @icecub https://prnt.sc/g85fwy same problem :/

Comment: @icecub spaces? please specify. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Try replacing the top of your code `<?` with `<?php ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` You'll see. Like here: `$_REQUEST ['u_uid'];` There's a space between REQUEST and [. And there are spaces after each mysqli_*: `']) ;`

Comment: @icecub OMG i totally forgot type in the php tag how did i not notice that. It works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Like Homer Simpson would say: Doh! :P Anyway, glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are a few issues here,

First of remove the header() redirect at the bottom and test/debug without that. Append something at the end like echo "success";

Note you are using:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

In here:

```
... VALUES ('$e_name', '$d_event', '$t_event', '$e_t_event', '$theme', '$date', '$id');
```

And from your form action you are not sending any GET data on your request, I'm pretty user your $id is empty so obviously your INSERT is failing, you are just not seeing any warnings or errors due to the header redirect (if condition is not met the second time and therefore warnings and errors are not visible). The code is being executed.

Also your u_uid, where is it coming from? There is nothing on your form sending this data.

NOTE: make sure to debug without the header() function you will not be able to output anything as per PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

As a good practice don't use header() on the same page just to add an additional GET value, do yourself a favor and create a new file, it will avoid confusion.