# form action not triggering instead redirecting to php script

Tags: php, html

what i'm trying to do is get the submitted name, email and message to my php script then send email message. The problem is my form action doesn't trigger instead it reloads the page.

**UPDATE**
Don't know what im missing from my html form here:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-demo" placeholder="Your Name">
        <span id="invalid-name">
            Please enter at least 2 chars
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="input-demo" placeholder="Email Address">
        <span id="invalid-email">
            Please enter valid email
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message">
        </textarea>
        <span id="invalid-message">
            Please write something for us
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book a Demo">
</form>
```

**UPDATE** 
php script first get values and contruct email message then finally send:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  include 'index.php';
  $to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
  $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = "Form submission";
  $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
  $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
  $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
  echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
  // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
} else {
  echo 'isset was false';
}
?>
```

Here's my folder structure

[image]

Im running this in localhost ubuntu apache server.

Comment: The form action is form-to-email.php `<form method="post" action="form-to-email.php">`, so of course if you submit the form it will get "redirected" there. (note: you are not using ajax)

Comment: I see i thought this is the way to trigger my php script. As i've followed the tutorial then google search. I haven't really understood after all.

Comment: Sorry, I am voting to close it.  You are posting to the php, thats why it is going there.  If you remove the script name from **action**, it will post to the same form.  And you can merge the two files.  But then the code in the php script is wrong in so many places.  Please merge teh two files and debug and repost any problems

Comment: found similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666854/form-method-post-not-working-not-running-php-file, i've installed php in my ubuntu but the problem still persist.

Comment: Please share more details. What's the **expected** behaviour? What do you mean by "redirects"?

Comment: Updated my post bro. remove the script from action just as @KenLee suggested.

Comment: Do this in your PHP script before the `IF` (I hope it's the one, single file) and send the form: 
`<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);` . You will be able to check all the variables of the POST request.

Comment: Thanks for the time in answering my novice question bro. Tried what you've suggested bro commented out my email code. then add ```<?php echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST);``` it does not output anything in console or network.

Comment: do i need to import my php script to my html file?

Comment: @Kael Please learn the basics of form handling: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your HTML is fine for one small thing, you didn't specify where to send the form after hitting submit. You do this by specifying the PHP script within the `action` parameter in `<form>`

```
<form method="post" action="form-to-email.php">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-demo" placeholder="Your Name">
        <span id="invalid-name">
            Please enter at least 2 chars
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="input-demo" placeholder="Email Address">
        <span id="invalid-email">
            Please enter valid email
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message">
        </textarea>
        <span id="invalid-message">
            Please write something for us
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book a Demo">
</form>
```

After reading your questions on someone elses answer I finally find out what you want, you can stop the site from staying on your phpscript page, by adding a header(Location: index.html) at the end of the script, so when it completed the registration or when it failed you send it back towards index. Alternatively you can include the PHP inside your index file but you will have to change your index from `.html` to `.php`

Example with redirect in your php script

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  include 'index.php';
  $to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
  $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = "Form submission";
  $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
  $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
  $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
  echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
  header('Location: index.html');
} else {
  echo 'isset was false';
  header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: You can refine the system by creating popups on the index.html with information regarding the redirect, or simply adding a small interval on the script page so that the user can read the message\

Comment: Yep tried this but some commenters told to remove the ```form-to-email.php``` in action. But i guess my problem was my ubuntu was not running php as i found in the post in stackoverflow. That's why its running now when i added my php script to the action.

Comment: Ah that explains! Anyways have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute of the form element you pasted is not set:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

With this attribute unset or empty, the form will submit to the current page because the browser has no way of knowing where to submit it to.
Assuming that form-to-email.php is the script to process, it should look like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="form-to-email.php">
```

Alternatively, you can access the PHP code in the HTML page by renaming index.html to index.php (PHP code in .html files won't be executed) and executing the PHP script from there, like so:

```
<?php
include "form-to-email.php";
?>
```

This should allow you to leave the action attribute blank and still have a functional form.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change field name from 'name' to any other word..

Try below code:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="full_name" class="input-demo" placeholder="Your Name">
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).